# Django Parse Post Request data (JsonArray)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have a model Example with 3 fields.

```
class Example(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
      number = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
      address = models.CharField(max_length=200)`
```

I have a Post API (rest framework). This would have array of objects. I want to parse this array and store each object in my database. This is the Views.py

```
class PostExample(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        example_records = request.POST["example_data"]
        print example_records
```

Here "example_data" is the key and value will be an array. Example value:

```
[
  {
    "name": "test",
    "address": "address",
    "number": 123456789
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

I am unable to loop through "example_records". "example_records" prints the array but not able to get each object from this. How to achieve this ??

Comment: use `json` module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json` module here. First convert your `example_records` string data into `json` object and then parse `Example value` and finally iterate through all.

```
import json
data = '''{"Example value":[{"name":"test1","address":"address1","number":123456789},{"name":"test2","address":"address2","number":123456789}]}'''
jobject = json.loads(data)
for val in jobject['Example value']:
    print(val)

{'address': 'address1', 'name': 'test1', 'number': 123456789}
{'address': 'address2', 'name': 'test2', 'number': 123456789}
```

Then you can simply extract `values` by passing its corresponding `key`, For example :

```
print(val['name'])
'test1'
'test2'
```

Answer (score 0):

`request.POST` is the raw data received during POST, which is a json string.
You could use the `json` module as suggested by some users but Django Rest Framework does the work for you: [request.data](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data). That is the whole point of using a framework like DRF.

```
class PostExample(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        example_records = request.data["example_data"]
        for record in example_records:
            ...
```