# What is the correct way of saving 200 objects in the database using django-rest-framework?

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, nested-loops

I have a problem to solve this next week in an project. I have a model with 3 fields, 2 of them are foreign key to other models and the other field is a simple string field. In the front-end I'm going to present to the user only a checkbox and a observation field, a string field that can be blank or null. There will be a list of checkbox, around 200. Each one will be a object in the database. I don't want to make a post request for each one of them, would make the user experience really bad, 200 fields are already really bad, but necessary in this case.

So I would like suggestions, code example about the best approach to accomplish this. Here is the model.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    observation = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I have a serializer and a ModelViewSet working for it with single request, a POST request of 1 object is working.

```
class PersonSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
```

I would like the front-end to send to the back-end a big list/array/object, not sure, and the back-end get this whole data in a single POST request and start the process to save it in the database. I was thinking If the best approach would be to iterate over this data and call the serializer on each one inside the view, or If I would implement a new type of serializer to make it.
I have read these two questions [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075575/django-rest-framework-loop-inside-json-object) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863269/django-parse-post-request-data-jsonarray) about it, and it was really helpful, but I still have doubts. And also another problem, If a error occurs, like let's say the server goes down in the middle of the process, the connection gets interrupted, something happens, then my data would be saved or would be interrupted in the middle, I'm asking because I can't have this data separated, I need to garantee the whole 200 fields gets saved or 0 field gets saved.

Comment: Just to clarify, the Model used is only an example, not the real case.

Comment: Can we see an example json that you will be sending. Or just make json  for your example models

Comment: Just for the example model is fine, the real model is different, but the type of value is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass list of data to serializer and validate all of it at once with passing many argument to serializer

```
example_data = [
 {'country': 1, 'user': 1, 'observation': ''},
 {'country': 1, 'user': 2, 'observation': ''},
 {'country': 2, 'user': 1, 'observation': ''},
 {'country': 2, 'user': 2, 'observation': ''},
]

serializer = PersonSerializer(data=example_data, many=True)

if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
```

It serializer will be valid if and only if all data instances are valid and will create object for each datum in data.

If you are concerned about failure at database level, you can always use atomic transaction in serializer's create method.

```
from django.db import transaction


class PersonSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        with transaction.atomic():
            return super().create(validated_data)
```

Comment: I'm doing something wrong, because it passes in the `serializer.is_valid()`, then pass `serializer.save()`, but when I check the database the data is not there, also in response I'm getting nothing, a empty brackets `[]`. Do I need to override the `create()` inside the serializer?